# PHP variable scope question

Tags: php, include, scope

According to the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) $a should be available to *b.inc* in the following code segment:

```
<?php
$a = 1;
include 'b.inc';
?>
```

However when I try to do the same when calling a static method, $a seems to be out of scope.

```
class foo {
    public static function bar() {
        $a = 1;
        include('b.inc');               
    }
}

foo::bar();
```

Am I misunderstanding something?
EDIT: Okay, I'm an idiot, everybody. I was using a wrapper function for the include -- to fill in the include path. This took the variable out of scope. Thanks for the help.

Comment: what is the contents of b.inc

Comment: let's say "echo $a;" for simplicity's sake.

Comment: You can also delete this question. There is also a SO badge for cleaning up ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It totally works for me.  If you are describing the problem accurately, something must be happening to $a inside of b.inc.

Comment: Thank you -- I must have screwed up somewhere. Apologies.

Comment: Yes. I also have my include in a foreach loop -- but I don't see how that would make any difference. I'll post my error when as soon as I figure it out.

Comment: Man!  No offense, Greg, but I seriously question your PHP proficiency if you are including a file in a loop.

Comment: It's just an HTML template to avoid putting a bunch of markup into the helper function. Is there a serious problem with this?

Comment: Okay -- even though this might not see a whole lot of iterations, I suppose that is more than just  a little herp derp on my part. The loop is in the template itself template now.

Comment: Awesome, that's by far a better place for the loop.  Just as Rasmus about looping inclusions.  He *rails* against them in his PHP talks.

Answer (score 1):

Function scope is different than the global scope. `b.inc` will see $a, and any variables created in `b.inc` will be in foo::bar()'s scope (unless they are defined as globals, or inside their own function scope).

You can test this with some code:

```
function foo() {
    $a = 1;
    include '1.php'; // modify and initialize, ie. $a++; $b = 3; 
    include '2.php'; // test the values: $a == 2; $b == 3
}
```

We run into this problem occasionally when we bootstrap WordPress in other scripts: the initialization scripts assume they are in the outermost scope so they will set variables like `$wpdb` (the database object), but that file will actually get created in some function that did a `require_once()`. The solution is to always bootstrap WordPress in the app before you get into any function scope.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the class you need to say that you mean the global one.

```
class foo {
    public static function bar() {
        global $a;
        var_dump($a);
    }
}

foo::bar();
```

Comment: You misunderstood his question.  He's saying that when he includes it in a static function, the file does not seem to see $a.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
//a.php
class test
{
    public static function run()
    {
        $a = 'Some value';
        include 'b.php'; //echo $a;
    }
}
test::run();
?>
```

all works fine in my test aswell.